# Is it possible to force SQL Server to create a wrong view?

Tags: sql-server, view

SQL Server has the capability to create a wrong synonym. For example:

```
create synonym Sample for NonExistingObject
```

This actually creates the `Sample` synonym.

Also it's possible to create a view that works, and later change the underlying tables that the view depends upon so that the view is non-functional anymore.

I'm creating a utility to automate some of the tasks related to the database and a lot of modules and lot of customers.

A problem that I'm facing is that some views depend upon non-existing objects that would be added later.

I wonder if it's possible to provide a flag to `create view` statement to force SQL Server to not validate view's definition and only build it?

Comment: Smells a little like a design problem. Should either create the view when the objects it depends on are created or find a different implementation. If you want to provide more concrete details of the design and the end goal, maybe we can provide a better path to get there.

Comment: @J.D. thank you for your suggestion. I think I can not explain my problem in details here, as it makes it off-topic. Any idea on how and where can I ask it?

Comment: You're certainly welcome to explain the problem you're trying to solve here, and if it's solvable with a reasonable database solution then it's definitely on-topic here. Otherwise a mod will move your question to StackOverflow if it's more on-topic for an application solution.

Answer (score 6):

No, the underlying table has to exist since sql server derives metadata for the columns that your view returns, as seen in sys.columns. You can of course create some temp stuff that the view refers to, or hardwire such as

```
SELECT col1 =CAST(23 AS int)
```

But I don't think that above is what you are looking for.

In other words: there's no deferred name resolution för views (like there is for stored procedures).